# near text "=" expecting "(" or " ' " or "."

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to create an entity to fill an array from signals, but I'm getting the following error: near text "=" expecting "(" or " ' " or "."

This is my vhdl code

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library work;
use work.all;

entity decryptionarray is 
    port(
        clk: in std_logic;
        key_in: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        encrypted_data : in std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
        encrypted_data_in : in std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
        decryption_key: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity decryptionarray;

architecture bhv of decryptionarray is
type deckeyarray is array (0 to 10) of std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
signal dkey, keyin : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal edatain, edata : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);

begin
    P0:process(clk) is 
        begin
            if(deckeyarray(10)/=null) then
                for j in 0 to 10 loop
                    deckeyarray(j)=null;
                end loop;

            else
                keyin <= key_in;
                edata <= encrypted_data;
                edatain <= encrypted_data_in ;
                dkey <= decryption_key ;
            end if;
    end process P0;
end architecture bhv;
```

Comment: You created a 'type' but you have to create a signal/variable with this type. "signal example_signal : deckeyarray;" Now you can use this signal in for-loop. A type is just like std_ulogic, etc. You always have to created a signal/variable based on a type.

Comment: (1) having declared a type, you might want to declare a signal of that type and operate on that signal not the type itself! (2) equality operator used in assignment statement (the reported error) (3) "null" is a reserved word and does not declare a valid std_logic_vector value.

Answer (score 2):

VHDL does not have compare with `null` as in `deckeyarray(10)/=null`, and `deckeyarray` is a type, not a signal.

To check for all 0's you can do:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
type deckeyarray_t is array (0 to 10) of std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
signal deckeyarray : deckeyarray_t;
...
if unsigned(deckeyarray(10)) = 0 then
```

The compare can also be made without the `unsigned` and `numeric_std`, but using `deckeyarray(10) = (deckeyarray(10)'range => '0')` instead.

To fill with all 0's you can do:

```
deckeyarray(j) <= (others => '0');
```

Note that the `decryption_key` output port is read in `dkey <= decryption_key;`, which does not make sense.

Comment: `decryption_key` is an output port